# Marklogic search Grammar NEAR Logic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using ML search grammar `abc NEAR\2 xyz`. The issue is `NEAR` looks in both directions.. Is it possible to tell ML to look in only one direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The Search API grammar `NEAR/` is parsed into a `cts:near-query`, which does not have directional options: https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:near-query.

**Update:** This is not documented anywhere but it may be worth a try. The Search API implementation appears to support parsing options from grammar definitions using a space delimited options attribute. Although none are provided in the [default options](https://docs.marklogic.com/search:get-default-options), you could override that by defining your own grammar in your search options.

Something like this might work:

```
<search:grammar>
  <search:joiner strength="30" apply="infix" options="ordered"
     element="cts:near-query" tokenize="word">NEAR</search:joiner>
</search:grammar>
```

Comment: Not directly about search:search, but cts:near-query has the ordered option.  So it is possible at some level.

Comment: @asusu This appears to be possible, assuming `ordered` satisfies your constraint for direction. For example, using ordered you could only query left-to-right, not right-to-left.

Comment: We generally discourage grammar customizations. You should considering using cts:parse instead if you want to leverage the "ordered" option.

Comment: @kcoleman Is it possible to configure `cts:parse` to run `NEAR` queries as `ordered` by default? The requirement to manually add the `[ordered]` token for every query may not be desirable.

Comment: No you cannot set default options. You could probably cobble something together with a generator function, but the syntax would be odd. For example, you could arrange for near:(abc xyz) to generate a cts:near-query with options of your choosing. See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/cts_query#id_13456.

Answer (score 5):

`cts:parse` grammar can take the ordered option,
`cts:parse("abc NEAR/2[ordered] xyz")`